# Scrapy ItemLoader item combining

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm attempting to use ItemLoader to combine three items into an array like this:

```
[
    {
        site_title: "Some Site Title",
        anchor_text: "Click Here",
        link: "http://example.com/page"
    }
]
```

As you can see in the JSON below, it's combining all items of a type together.

How should I be handling this to output a JSON with arrays like I'm looking for?

Spider file:

```
import scrapy
from linkfinder.items import LinkfinderItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class LinksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "links"
    allowed_domains = ["wpseotest.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://wpseotest.com"]

    def parse(self, response):

        l = ItemLoader(item=LinkfinderItem(), response=response)
        l.add_xpath('site_title', '//title/text()')
        l.add_xpath('anchor_text', '//a//text()')
        l.add_xpath('link', '//a/@href')
        return l.load_item()

        pass
```

Items.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import item, Field

class LinkfinderItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    site_title = Field()
    anchor_text = Field()
    link = Field()
    pass
```

JSON Output

```
[
{"anchor_text": ["Globex Corporation", "Skip to content", "Home", "About", "Globex News", "Events", "Contact Us", "3999 Mission Boulevard,\r", "San Diego, CA 92109", "This is a test scheduled\u00a0post.", "Test Title", "Globex Subsidiary Ice Cream Inc. Creates Chicken Wing\u00a0Flavor", "Globex Inc.", "\r\n", "Blog at WordPress.com."], "link": ["https://wpseotest.com/", "#content", "https://wpseotest.com/", "https://wpseotest.com/about/", "https://wpseotest.com/globex-news/", "https://wpseotest.com/events/", "https://wpseotest.com/contact-us/", "http://maps.google.com/maps?z=16&q=3999+mission+boulevard,+san+diego,+ca+92109", "https://wpseotest.com/2016/08/19/this-is-a-test-scheduled-post/", "https://wpseotest.com/2016/06/28/test-title/", "https://wpseotest.com/2015/10/18/globex-subsidiary-ice-cream-inc-creates-chicken-wing-flavor/", "https://wpseotest.wordpress.com", "https://wordpress.com/?ref=footer_blog"], "site_title": ["Globex Corporation \u2013 We make things better, or, sometimes, worse."]}
]
```

Comment: you can use piplines to make/create your desire output

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to yield an item for every link here?
To get that that what you want to do is find article nodes, then iterate through them and find the fields that you later combine into a dictionary/scrapy.Item.

```
def parse(self, response):
    site_title = response.xpath("//title/text()").extract_first() 
    links = response.xpath("//a")
    for link in links:
        l = ItemLoader(selector=link)
        l.add_value('site_title', site_title)
        l.add_xpath('anchor_text', 'text()')
        l.add_xpath('link', '@href')
        yield l.load_item()
```

Now you can run `scrapy crawl myspider -o output.json` and you should be getting something like:

```
{[
    {"site_title": "title",
     "anchor_text": "foo",
     "link": "http://foo.com"},
    {"site_title": "title",
     "anchor_text": "bar",
     "link": "http://bar.com"}
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: I ended up using a pipeline; I could never get your example to work. I'm not sure if there's something else that would cause it to not work correctly.

Comment: I have it uploaded to the repo here (the version using pipelines) https://github.com/chrisfromthelc/scrapy-linkfinder if you see anything glaring that was causing issues, that wasn't in your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

@Granitosaurus, I did this originally, even before using items/itemloader and simply building a dictionary with this method.

Then I found out about itemloaders, I said heck I should probably used that,(thinking it's better performance). Well that resulted in me getting the OP's results and trying to figure out how to put it back together, how I had it before when I was simply building my own dictionary.

Now I'm inclined to just do this how I did (same as your method) just with item and item loader included.

This seems like most easiest to understand. In my example I have set of products found by

```
product_items = //div[contains(@class,"item-div")]
```

I iterate on them and extract product details. Then I simply placed them into a dictionary.

```
        for item in product_items:
            name = item.xpath(product_name).extract_first()
            print(name)
            if name not in products:
                products[name] = {}
                products[name].update({'product_supplier': item.xpath(product_supplier).extract_first(),
                                       'product_weight': item.xpath(product_weight).extract_first(),
                                       'product_image': item.xpath(product_image).extract_first(),
                                       'a_level': item.xpath(a_level).extract_first(),
                                       'b_level': item.xpath(b_level).extract_first(),
                                       'price_tag': item.xpath(price_tag).extract_first().strip()
                                     })
```

now with items/itemloader I'll do `selector=link` and it should be a similar method as I did before. I wonder if I wasted my time trying to make it work through items and item loader though. Figuring this out fully was Grimmy a good day spent.

I guess eventually I'll use pipelines or feed export. However, I haven't really found a benefit from them online besides that the code looks clean.